# how can I invert the weight paint of dynamic paint?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have a surface with all vertex weith set to 1, when the object set to brush in dynamic paint came over, the vertex must be setted to weight 0.
Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

In Weight Tools panel in the left, there's a option "Invert", it solves your problem?

[image]

Comment: I need the inversion for animation

Answer (score 1):

Use a VertexWeightMix modifier to subtract your non-inverted (dynamic weight painted) vertex group from your base vertex group, effectively inverting the animated (weight painted) vertex group.
Example: I have a "pinned group" that is all set to 1. I dynamic painted a "paint group" that paints 1's on a base model weight of 0 (red painting on blue).  Then, I use VetrexWeightMix modifier and subtract B from A, and now I have the animation of blues being painted on red instead of the red painted on blue.  I hope that was clear enough.